# Fall back to default user for child processes after impersonation

Tags: c#, windows, impersonation

My application is typically started by UserA as UserB, using `System.Process.Start("app.exe", "UserB", "secret")`.

Now, I want app.exe to spawn additional child processes, but as UserA, without the additional privileges UserB has.

Is there a way to accomplish that wihout asking UserA for his password?

I tried just using System.Process.Start without credentials, as well as calling `cmd /C child.exe`, but both approaches launch `child.exe` as UserB. I was thinking about a way to ask the current shell to launch the child process for me, but I found nothing yet.

Comment: I don't think that you can, (and it could be quite dangerous if User A were the user with additional privileges)

Comment: Good point. In this light, I suspect you're right. Maybe `app.exe` can be granted appropriate privileges. I control the start there tightly so I could set those. If they exist. =)

Comment: If you're controlling that launch, can't some kind of back-channel be arranged between `appX` (the one doing the launch) and `app.exe` so that the latter can request that the former (still running as User A) launches the new processes?

Comment: That could be done, yes. It would invovle more work than I hoped, but it is a solution. Why not post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is for the launching application could make a copy of its own security token and allow the child process to inherit the handle to it.  The handle value can be passed on the command line or via an environment variable.

Note that this effectively gives User B unrestricted access to user A's account.

Comment: Interesting idea, thanks! I am not sure on how to pass the handle to the child process, do you have a hint there? Simple passing the WindowsIdentity.Token in some form would not work (as fas as I know), since it is just a pointer and the child process would have its own address space and could not use it to access the token's memory location. Or do I have something wrong here? =)

Comment: It seems likely that .NET has no built-in support for doing this, so you'll have to use native functions via P/Invoke.  See `DuplicateTokenEx` and `SetHandleInformation`.  I don't see an option in `System.Diagnostics.Process` to explicitly control handle inheritance, but it does support redirecting input and output which requires inheritance to be enabled, so I guess either it is enabled by default or only when you redirect the input or output.  I assume you could maybe use `SafeHandle.SetHandle` to bring the imported handle into the .NET world.

Comment: Alternatively you could launch all the subprocesses via P/Invoke or perhaps use a native DLL and native executable wrapper to do that part of the job.